# Fetch data from DB in UserSpice

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am newbie to PHP and Mysql , so kindly forgive me if i looks silly

I am working on making a web app over UserSpice Framework .

My query is i need to display the role of the user logged in . Like if he is Administrator then echo as Administrator

I am taking Permission id of the logged in user from users table and comparing it with the permission id in Permission table and trying to fetch the name of the role from the permission table . But it displays the following error .

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\***\account.php on line 477 
Array
```

My query is as follows

```
<?php 
$query =$db->query("select name from permission where permission.id=users.permissions"); 
$results = $query->results(); 
echo $results; 
?>
```

For information:

Permission Table has two fields id and name .

Users table has lots of fields where id is one among them which has the same value of id as in permission table .

Comment: `$results` is obviously an array. Use `print_r($results);` in replace of `echo`

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the reply . After making that changes i am getting as `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 100 ) )`

Comment: You can access that using `$results[0]->id;`

Comment: @Matt actually it outputs as 100 . The point is i want to output the name field in Permission table which is "Administrator" also by the way there is no such id as 100 mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the required output , so thought it might help others so i am answering my own question.

```
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_permission_matches WHERE user_id = ?", array($user->data()->id));
$x = $query->results(true); //dump($x); 
foreach ($x as $y){ //dump($y); 
$perm_id=$y["permission_id"]; 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM permission WHERE id = ?", array($perm_id)); 
$z = $query->results(true); //dump($z[0]); 
$perm_name=$z[0]["name"]; 
echo $perm_name.'<br/>';; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for using UserSpice! I hope you're enjoying it.  If there's anything I can do to help you along, let me know.   You can always message me here or over on the forums at userspice.com

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I've never seen User Spice before, but it looks like it's based on PDO.

What's happening is $query->results() is giving you an array (of records returned from the DB) of arrays (and each of those records is an array of fields), even if you should be getting back one field from one record. With this particular function, much like a spreadsheet, whether you have one or 10000 cells filled, you need to specify which column (field) and row (record) the value is in before you can work with it. You can't just echo an array of arrays, hence the Array to string conversion notice.

It sounds like there are some fundamentals that you should probably brush up on. Rather than giving you the my generic advice, I'd check out the part 3 of their DB class video tutorial (http://www.userspice.com/documentation-db-class-2/) to not only secure some of those basics, but get an idea of how to do things the way your framework wants you to do it. These sorts of things are often a lot tougher if you're not using the tool the way the creator intended it to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice mate . I will look into that as you mentioned . However in their documentation they mentioned that we can use general and common structures and no framework generic structure is needed to work on this framework . Might be watching that video will give me a clear picture . Thanks mate .

Comment: @RajaGopal Good luck. That third video does detail exactly how you query a database, and get results using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
$sql= "select name from permission where id=users.permissions";
$rslt = $conn->query($sql);

foreach($rslt as $newArray){
    $roleName = $newArray['name'];
    echo "$roleName<br>";
}
```

Comment: Mate in my case its not `$conn->query($sql);` rather its `$db->query($sql);` . however now i am getting no error no output mate .